# Few questions over the redirection stuff?

Tags: java, jsp

```
UTIL.getServletPath("/SetupPage?PG=setupusersettings") %>">
```

1. What is SetupPage. Is it an directory?
2. Why ? is used?
3. What is PG?
4. setupusersettings is an jsp page, all i can find and it will redirect to that page.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask one of your colleagues instead? :)

Comment: I did ask, but no help so asked u guys here for help

Comment: If they don't want to help you, you have problems even SO cannot solve.

Comment: @bzlm - John didn't say that they *don't want* to help. He just said, he didn't get some help (maybe they don't know too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to learn the basics of web programming. You can find millions of stuffs on Web about it. Shortly;
/SetupPage?PG=setupusersettings

1. SetupPage seems like a web application, you requested. Basicly, as soon as you call /SetupPage, the request will be sent to this application.
2. "?" is a seperator. after that, you can send parameters (you can send parameters using HTTP GET/POST) to this application. In this case, the name of parameter is PG and the value "setupusersettings". For exampe, you can access the value of this parameter in your web application
3. Google "Web programming java servlet tutorial"

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the resulting link (URL) it will (literally) *"call the resource `/SetupPage` with the attribute/value pair `[PG -> setupusersettings]`"*.

`PG` is an attribute name (could be an acronym for *Page*).

Look for a resource named "SetupPage.???" (could be a python/perl script or any other executable file). You may have to look at the http servers configuration files to get the local location of this file. The redirection to is most probably done by this executable.

Comment: Python/Perl script? Isn't it more likely that `SetupPage` is just a plain old servlet that redirects to the jsp page specified by `PG`?

Comment: @bzlm - yeah, maybe you're right. Maybe this is more accurate: "SetupPage is some code based component".